# JavaScript Substring Not Taking User Input

Tags: javascript, input, substring

I have a paragraph of text and want a user to be able to type in the numbers for where a substring should start and end, then have that substring of text printed out when they click a button. But nothing happens when the button is clicked.

Google Chrome gives me this error on the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined

HTML

```
<div>
    <h3 id="sentence">You can input numbers below and it will return that interval of characters from this sentence.</h3>
    <input type="text" id="input1">
    <input type="text" id="input2">
    <button type="button" onclick="interval()">Submit</button>
    <p id="intervalAnswer"></p>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function interval() { 
var inputStart = document.getElementById("input1").value
var inputEnd = document.getElementById("input2").value
var string = document.getElementById("sentence").value;
var result  = string.substring(inputStart, inputEnd);
document.getElementById("intervalAnswer").innerHTML = result;
}
```

Comment: For `<h3>` use `innerHTML` instead of `value`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var string = document.getElementById("sentence").textContent;
```

This was your problem, h3 does not have value.